# Check blank before create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

For some reason, the POST method is allowing me to create Telefono_paciente even if I do not have all the required fields.

```
# Create a new telefono_paciente
def post(self, request):
    serializer = Telefono_pacienteSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)



class Telefono_paciente(models.Model): 
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True, blank=False, choices=PHONE_CHOICES)
    Paciente = models.ForeignKey(Paciente, null=True, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.tipo, self.lada, self.telefono)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = "Pacientes - Telefonos"
```

Answer (score 0):

The two model's field have `null=True` which makes then non required.